# How to remove registry value and key from registry entry

Tags: registry

I already setting key and value in the registry entry by using `RegSetValueExA`, and it's created . But Now I want to delete that key and value from registry entry and for that I am using `RegDeleteKey` but its giving error 2 which is "The system cannot find the file specified.", can you tell me how can I solve this.

Comment: Could you post the code? We can't help you if we don't know what you're passing the functions.

Answer (score 4):

Can you show any codes at all? It doesn't help anyone here narrow down your problem.

If I would take a guess though, there's something wrong with the way you have specified *LPCTSTR lpSubKey* in either RegOpenKeyEx or RegDeleteKey.

Example:

If you created a key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test
```

In order to delete it, you would need something like this:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &RegHandle)
RegDeleteKey(RegHandle, test)
```

**OR**

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, someNullValue, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &RegHandle)
RegDeleteKey(RegHandle, L"Software\\test")
```

Make sure you check out the functions again at MSDN.

[RegDeleteKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724845%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Does the registry key have sub-keys?  `RegDeleteKey` won't do a recursive delete.  If you're writing for Vista+, you can use `RegDeleteTree`, otherwise you will have to code a recursive delete, but there's example code on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724235%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You can also use [`SHDeleteKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773486%28VS.85%29.aspx) out of shlwapi.dll.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check for error 2 / "file not found":

- Make sure it's not a "value" within a key instead of an actual key.

If you create a folder like HKCU > Software > CompanyName and then store a value like option = "foo" with RegSetValueEx, then you need to delete this with RegDeleteValue or RegDeleteValueEx.

- If it's a 64-bit OS, there are separate registry views for 32-bit vs. 64-bit.  By default a 32-bit app will use the 32-bit view for everything but if you created the entry using KEY_WOW64_64KEY for some reason then you need to use that when deleting.

Comment: Good advice on the difference between `RegDeleteKey` and `RegDeleteValue`, that had me scratching my head for a bit.