# search registry for value if match found delete parent key

Tags: vbscript

I need help with a script that would traverse through the registry for a particular value and once match is found delete the parent key. I have found a code but it does not work. I suspect that is in not traversing through the registry key for match.

```
Option Explicit

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE   = &H80000002 
Const cRegKeyStartingPath  = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
Const cRegValueToFind      = "Ossec HIDS"
Const cRegDataToMatch      = "DisplayName" 

Dim oReg, subkey, arrSubKeys, sCurrentKey, sCurrentValuePath, iDeletedCount
iDeletedCount = 0

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, cRegKeyStartingPath, arrSubKeys

On Error Resume Next
For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
    If Err.Number = 0 Then 'in case the collection is empty
        sCurrentKey = "HKLM\" & cRegKeyStartingPath & subkey
        sCurrentValuePath = sCurrentKey & "\" & cRegValueToFind
        If customRegRead(sCurrentValuePath) = cRegDataToMatch Then
            WScript.Echo "Going to delete "&sCurrentKey
            DeleteRegKey sCurrentKey&"\"
            iDeletedCount = iDeletedCount + 1
        End If
    Else
        iDeletedCount = -1
    End If
Next

Select Case iDeletedCount
    Case 0
        WScript.Echo "No matching keys found"
    Case -1
        WScript.Echo "No subkeys found below HKLM\"&cRegKeyStartingPath
    Case Else
        WScript.Echo "Deleted " & iDeletedCount & " keys"
End Select

Function customRegRead(sRegValue)

    Dim oShell
    Dim sRegReturn

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    sRegReturn = oShell.RegRead(sRegValue)
    If Err.Number<>0 Then
        customRegRead = "Failed To Read Value"
    Else
        customRegRead = sRegReturn
    End If  

End Function

Sub DeleteRegKey(sKey)

    Dim oShell
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    oShell.RegDelete sKey

End Sub
```

If there is something cleaner/better please advise.

Comment: Did you confirm that the `cRegKeyStartingPath` points to a valid location in your registry? On my machine (Windows 7), I have `Windows NT` instead of just `Windows`. Also - when you are debugging it's often a good idea to turn off the `On Error` statement - it helps if there's an unexpected error.

Comment: The CRegKeystartingpath is valid. I do not code but I suspect that this is not going through the subkeys.

Comment: If you are not experienced in writing code I would SERIOUSLY advise you against attempting to access / modify the registry with code you do not understand...

Comment: I am doing this in a test environment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to remove all occurrences of `On Error Resume Next` and stick with WMI methods. Also your current code doesn't use recursion, so you can only find values in immediate subkeys of `cRegKeyStartingPath`. You'll need recursion for traversing a tree of arbitrary depth.

Use [`EnumValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390388) to enumerate the values of a given key:

```
rc = reg.EnumValues(HKLM, key, names, types)
```

The method returns 0 on success, so you can check for errors by evaluating the return code. After the call finishes the variable `names` contains an array with the names of the values in `key`, or `Null` if the key did not contain any values (short of the default value, that is). So the code for checking if a particular value exists in a given key might look like this:

```
reg.EnumValues HKLM, key, names, types
If Not IsNull(names) Then
  For Each name In names
    If name = "foo" Then
      reg.GetStringValue HKLM, key, name, data
      If data = "bar" Then
        'delete key here
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
  Next
End If
```

You can traverse the registry by enumerating the subkeys of a given key via [`EnumKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390387) and recursing into those subkeys:

```
Sub TraverseRegistry(root, key)
  reg.EnumKey root, key, subkeys
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      TraverseRegistry root, key & "\" & sk
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

To delete a key use the [`DeleteKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389869) method. The information which key must be deleted is something you already have: it's the value of the variable `key` from the value enumeration routine when `found` is true. However, you can't delete a key that has subkeys, so you must delete *those* first. Something for which you can re-use the traversal routine from above:

```
Sub DelKey(root, key)
  reg.EnumKey root, key, subkeys
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      DelKey root, key & "\" & sk  'delete subkeys first
    Next
  End If
  'at this point all subkeys have already been deleted, so we can
  'now delete the parent key
  reg.DeleteKey root, key
End Sub
```

Put everything together and you get something like this:

```
Const HKLM = &h80000002

Const StartKey    = "SOFTWARE\Wow...ion\Uninstall"
Const SearchValue = "DisplayName"
Const MatchData   = "Ossec HIDS"

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

FindAndDeleteKey HKLM, StartKey, SearchValue, MatchData

Sub FindAndDeleteKey(root, key, value, data)
  reg.EnumValues HKLM, key, names, types
  If Not IsNull(names) Then
    For Each name In names
      If name = value Then
        reg.GetStringValue HKLM, key, name, regdata
        If regdata = data Then
          DelKey root, key
          Exit Sub
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End If

  'value not found in current key => continue search in subkeys
  reg.EnumKey root, key, subkeys
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      FindAndDeleteKey root, key & "\" & sk, value, data
    Next
  End If
End Sub

Sub DelKey(root, key)
  reg.EnumKey root, key, subkeys
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      DelKey root, key & "\" & sk  'delete subkeys first
    Next
  End If
  'at this point all subkeys have already been deleted, so we can
  'now delete the parent key
  reg.DeleteKey root, key
End Sub
```

Since you're looking for a particular value with particular data you could even simplify `FindAndDeleteKey()` to this:

```
Sub FindAndDeleteKey(key)
  'Try to read the value directly. If the value doesn't exist this will
  'simply return a non-zero return code and set data to Null.
  reg.GetStringValue HKLM, key, SearchValue, data
  If Not IsNull(data) Then
    'value does exist
    If data = MatchData Then
      DelKey HKLM, key
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If

  'value not found in current key => continue search in subkeys
  reg.EnumKey HKLM, key, subkeys
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      FindAndDeleteKey key & "\" & sk
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:** Below is a version that generates some debug output. Run it in a command prompt via `cscript debug_sample.vbs`. Note that since you want to delete stuff in HKLM you **must** run the script "as Administrator" when UAC is enabled.

```
Const HKLM = &h80000002

Const StartKey    = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
Const SearchValue = "DisplayName"
Const MatchData   = "Ossec HIDS"

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

FindAndDeleteKey StartKey

Sub FindAndDeleteKey(key)
  WScript.Echo "[HKLM\" & key & "]"
  rc = reg.GetStringValue(HKLM, key, SearchValue, data)
  If Not IsNull(data) Then
    WScript.Echo """" & SearchValue & """=""" & data & """"
    If data = MatchData Then
      DelKey HKLM, key
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Else
    WScript.Echo "'" & SearchValue & "' not found in [HKLM\" & key & "], rc=" & rc
  End If

  reg.EnumKey HKLM, key, subkeys
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      FindAndDeleteKey key & "\" & sk
    Next
  End If
End Sub

Sub DelKey(root, key)
  reg.EnumKey root, key, subkeys
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      DelKey root, key & "\" & sk
    Next
  End If
  rc = reg.DeleteKey(root, key)
  WScript.Echo "Deleting [HKLM\" & key & "], rc=" & rc
End Sub
```

I was able to reproduce a return code 6 (handle is invalid) with an invalid `hDefKey` value, e.g. `&h8000002` (only 7 digits) or `h80000002` (missing ampersand).

Comment: Wow thanks for the scriptAnd the breakdowns and the explanations. however I can't get the script to runI and delete the registry keys. Am I doing something wrong

Comment: @user347258 Hard to tell without any information. I'd start with checking the return codes of the methods, particularly `DeleteKey`: `rc = reg.DeleteKey root, key : WScript.Echo key & ": " & rc`. I omitted those checks from my sample code for simplicity reasons. Verify that the strings you compare against are spelled correctly. The checks in my sample code are case-sensitive. Also check for or remove leading/trailing whitespace (`Trim()`).

Comment: below is trimmed version of the registry export.  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2BBD373C-E9E2-4A64-A17C-FC3F5BE25B7E}]
"DisplayName"="Ossec HIDS"
"Language"=dword:00000409
"Version"=dword:02070000
"WindowsInstaller"=dword:00000001
"DisplayVersion"="2.7.0"
"Comments"="Ossec HIDS (2.7.0)
I have copied and pasted the values. I am a novice programmer. I am trying my best to understand the code. I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @user347258 You switched value and data. Use these instead: `Const SearchValue = "DisplayName" : Const MatchData = "Ossec HIDS"`

Comment: Had already tried that. Still no go. FYI I am running on win 8 x64.

Comment: keep getting "expected end of statament" error when I try to use rc = reg.DeleteKey root,. Also, I believe you are correct the Delete function is not getting called.

Comment: @user347258 See the example I gave for `EnumValues`. When using the methods in an assignment (`rc = ...`) you must put the argument list in parentheses.

Comment: I put rc =..in the following section. My logic could be off..but I get nothing..Sub DelKey(root, key)
  reg.EnumKey root, key, subkeys
   If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      DelKey root, key & "\" & sk  'delete subkeys first
    Next
  End If
 rc = reg.DeleteKey (root, key) 
 WScript.Echo key & ": " & rc
  'at this point all subkeys have already been deleted, so we can
  'now delete the parent key
End Sub

Comment: @user347258 If nothing is echoed `DelKey` is never called, so you need to find out why that is. I updated my answer with a debug version of the script. Also, please avoid posting longer code snippets in comments. It's tends to be near unreadable. If you must post something like that it's better to update your question with it.

Comment: Ok. I think delkey is called but I getting the following message. Line 17, char 7. Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment "delkey"

Comment: Ok, I think i figured out the error message. I changed the line to say DelKey root, key. I see the msg box displaying deleting..but it does not delete the key. I am running this as an Administrator.

Comment: By "run as administrator" I mean: righ-click the Command Prompt (or PowerShell) icon, select "Run as administrator" from the context menu, enter `cscript C:\path\to\your\script.vbs` and press [Enter]. Sorry about the error in line 17. I seem to have mistakenly deleted the `HKLM` argument when updating the answer. Apologies.

Comment: That is exactly how I am running the script but does not delete the registry key.

Comment: Change the line `reg.DeleteKey root, key` into `rc = reg.DeleteKey(root, key) : WScript.Echo "DeleteKey rc=" & rc`. What is the output? Check the permissions on the key (it's possible that Administrators don't have write/delete permissions).

Comment: I did some research that vista+ does support regdeletekey function for recursive delete. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475523/how-to-remove-registry-value-and-key-from-registry-entry. In the meantime I will try what you had suggested.

Comment: Functions for recursive deletion may exist for C++ or .NET, but that has nothing to do with VBScript. Return code 6 means AFAICS that the interpreter thinks that the handle is invalid. I was able to reproduce that return code when using an invalid `hDefKey` value, e.g. `&h8000002` (only 7 digits) or `h80000002` (missing ampersand).

Comment: ok. Understood. What is causing the handle to be invalid? Do I need to change anything?

Comment: No idea. The code itself works. Anything else is AFAICS an issue with either Windows 8 or your script file (typo, encoding, ...).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will investigate further. You have been very patient and helpful.