# Registry - HKEY_USERS Recursively Delete Key (VBS)

Tags: recursion, vbscript, registry, profile

I would like to delete the following value recursively through the User Profiles/HKEY_USERS location.  This is what I got so far. However I cannot get the script to delete the value under "strKeyPath" variable.  I have removed what I did before as it was very wrong.

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001  
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002  
Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003  

'Set the local computer as the target

strComputer = "."

'set the objRegistry Object 
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

'Enumerate All subkeys in HKEY_USERS
objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_USERS, "", arrSubkeys

'Define variables
strKeyPath = "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\50cc940dd0f54608"
strSID = "S-1-5-21-\d*-\d*-\d*-\d*\\"
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15347887/1630171) help?

Comment: I guess I don't know how to integrate that information into the script.

Comment: Take a closer look at the procedure `TraverseRegistry` and try to understand what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve isn't really 'recursion', you're just deleting a registry key from a number of different places. This is how I'd do it:

```
Option Explicit

Const HKU = &H80000003

Dim wmi, reg
Dim prof, profs
Dim key

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")

Set profs = wmi.ExecQuery("Select SID from Win32_UserProfile where SID like 'S-1-5-21%'")

For Each prof In profs
  key = prof.SID & "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\50cc940dd0f54608"
  WScript.Echo key
  'Call reg.DeleteKey(HKU, key) 'commented out for safety
Next
```

The WMI query matches all user profiles on the system, the same as your regular expression, and the result of it is used to build a registry path.

Please be careful when deleting from the registry

Comment: That's awesome I didn't think of using WMI in the registry.

Comment: Do you know if that will work over Windows XP, I have WMI enabled on XP but perhaps I need to create one for XP?  It works great over Windows 7,8, and 8.1

Comment: For others reading this: The Win32_UserProfile class doesn't exist in Windows XP